# KeyError: "[''] not in index" while normalizing multiple specific columns, using StandardScaler()

Tags: python, scikit-learn, normalization

Trying to normalize only specific numeric columns, using `StandartScaler()`

Checked several SO questions, but failed to resolve.

All columns are floats or integers

```
cols_to_norm = ['A','B','C']

train_data[cols_to_norm] = StandardScaler().fit_transform(train_data[cols_to_norm])

KeyError: "['A'] not in index"
```

Column A is float64.

Current DF

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `train_data` does have index `A` (if not then it won't work anyway).

You are using those indexes incorrectly. If you want to select multiple columns, you need to use double bracket syntax (otherwise your list of column names will be treated as separate arguments)

```
train_data[[cols_to_norm]]
```

Here is a quick example.

**data.csv**

```
a,b,c
1,1,0
2,3,4
1,0,0
```

**app.py**

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

df = pd.read_csv("./data.csv")
print(df.values)

# [[1 1 0]
#  [2 3 4]
#  [1 0 0]]

scaler = StandardScaler()

df[['a', 'b']] = scaler.fit_transform(df[['a', 'b']])
print(df)

#           a         b  c
# 0 -0.707107 -0.267261  0
# 1  1.414214  1.336306  4
# 2 -0.707107 -1.069045  0
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, but slightly differently. Using your approach I get a weird error `NameError: name 'scaler' is not defined`

Comment: and have you defined it? `scaler = StandardScaler()`

Comment: Yep, this one is fixed, sorry, but still now luck, the same error. I will update with a pic of output. What should I print to double check?

Comment: The code above works as is so you should try to copy/paste it and replace mine values with yours and it should work. If it doesn't then you are most likely loading a dataframe that doesn't have column named `A`. If it doesn't work then post your updated code together with a sample csv data so that it is testable,

Comment: Print the head of your dataframe as well.

Comment: My df is 132 columns :( not sure if you want it here.

Comment: what is the output of `print('interest_date' in train_data.columns)`?

Comment: I sincerely apologize. I did the most stupid typo in my life. `interest_date` instead of `interest_rate`! OMG, what a dummy. Thank you so much for your time, I accepted, hopefully will be helpful for the community.

Comment: That happens :)